# Artifactory Configuration Fails To Start

Tags: artifactory

We have Artifactory v6.20.1 running on Ubuntu 16.04. The install was managed via apt-get. Someone accidentally ran an upgrade that moved us to v7. Unfortunately, that breaks some of our tooling so we needed to revert.

We performed a clean install, updated it to use a local PostgreSQL database, and everything started up fine. We have nightly backups of Artifactory, so we performed a system import from our previous nights backup. At this point everything still seemed to be behaving properly - could see all our artifacts and previous configuration settings - and the system appeared back to normal.

Then we did a system reboot to apply some system level changes (kernel update) and everything went south. After the reboot Artifactory would no longer start. The error we are seeing in the logs is this...

```
2020-08-07 16:33:12,906 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.c.CentralConfigServiceImpl:757) - Could not load configuration due to: Failed to read object from stream
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read object from stream
    at org.artifactory.jaxb.JaxbHelper.read(JaxbHelper.java:131)
    at org.artifactory.jaxb.JaxbHelper.readConfig(JaxbHelper.java:66)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.reader.CentralConfigReader.readAndConvert(CentralConfigReader.java:76)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.reader.CentralConfigReader.read(CentralConfigReader.java:58)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.getCentralConfigDescriptorCache(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:737)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.access$000(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:110)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl$1.call(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl$1.call(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.security.service.VersioningCacheImpl.get(VersioningCacheImpl.java:86)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.getDescriptor(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.getDescriptor(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy169.getDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.getAccessClientSettings(ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.java:635)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.lambda$getAccessServerSettings$9(ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.java:597)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4876)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4871)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.getAccessServerSettings(ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.java:581)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.newClientBuilder(ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.java:137)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.buildAccessClient(AccessServiceImpl.java:355)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.bootstrapAccessClient(AccessServiceImpl.java:1254)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessService(AccessServiceImpl.java:339)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessClientIfNeeded(AccessServiceImpl.java:328)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.init(AccessServiceImpl.java:321)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy183.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:274)
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:154)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:211)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$200(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:67)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:92)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: null
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:578)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:264)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:125)
    at org.artifactory.jaxb.JaxbHelper.read(JaxbHelper.java:129)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.4.3: Type 'xs:string' is not validly derived from the type definition, 'IDREF', of element 'repositoryRef'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:453)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3231)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.getAndCheckXsiType(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2557)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1936)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:741)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:101)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:168)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
2020-08-07 16:33:12,913 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:96) - Application could not be initialized: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:211)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$200(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:67)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:92)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to initialize bean 'org.artifactory.security.access.AccessService'.; nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:276)
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:154)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2051)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4871)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.getAccessServerSettings(ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.java:581)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.newClientBuilder(ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.java:137)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.buildAccessClient(AccessServiceImpl.java:355)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.bootstrapAccessClient(AccessServiceImpl.java:1254)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessService(AccessServiceImpl.java:339)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessClientIfNeeded(AccessServiceImpl.java:328)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.init(AccessServiceImpl.java:321)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy183.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:274)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.artifactory.security.access.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.getAccessClientSettings(ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.java:635)
    at org.artifactory.security.access.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.lambda$getAccessServerSettings$9(ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore.java:597)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4876)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

I'm *guessing* that this means there is some sort of error in the `artifactory.config.latest.xml`, but these log entries don't even contain enough information to tell me that. I can't share the full contents of that file because we've got some internal stuff in there. I did look at the `<repositoryRef>` elements that were referenced in the errors, but didn't see anything crazy. I couldn't find the XSD the XML file references to do a validation check.

Any information or ideas would be appreciated. Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the Artifactory configuration was migrated to v7. Try to replace the configuration with the a verified xml (one that works for v6).

To do that simply change the word `latest` to `import` for `artifactory.config.latest.xml`. Read more [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuration+Files#ConfigurationFiles-BootstrappingtheGlobalConfiguration)

Comment: So I found that same page and the 'import' renaming does get the system accessible again. I get the configuration migrating to v7, but this configuration was restored from a good backup from my v6 system. I had also done a clean v6 re-install, so I'm not sure where the v7 influence may be coming from. Regardless, it seems to be resolve the issue.