# HTTP Settings Changes Corrupt Artifactory Configuration

Tags: artifactory

I had an issue with a system that was accidentally upgraded from v6 to v7 through `apt` that I detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63309033/artifactory-configuration-fails-to-start). Somehow, my configuration was getting corrupted. I was able to overcome that issue by renaming my configuration file (which was from a known good backup of my v6 system prior to accidental upgrade) from `latest` to `import`. Things seemed well and good after that.

However, in the process of verifying my Apache proxy settings, I've run into another issue. If I try to save my HTTP Settings in the admin, I get the following error in the logs...

```
2020-08-08 07:41:07,879 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [ERROR] (o.a.c.CentralConfigServiceImpl:655) - Failed to reload configuration: org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.ReverseProxyDescriptor cannot be cast to org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.RepoDescriptor
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.ReverseProxyDescriptor cannot be cast to org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.RepoDescriptor
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.backup.BackupDescriptor.getExcludedRepositories(BackupDescriptor.java:143)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.backup.DiffFunctionsImpl.backupDescriptor(DiffFunctionsImpl.java:32)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.backup.DiffFunctionsImpl.lambda$new$2(DiffFunctionsImpl.java:42)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.backup.DiffFunctionsImpl.diffFor(DiffFunctionsImpl.java:16)
    at org.jfrog.common.config.diff.DiffUtils.diffInternalClass(DiffUtils.java:92)
    at org.jfrog.common.config.diff.DiffUtils.diffByType(DiffUtils.java:56)
    at org.jfrog.common.config.diff.DiffUtils.lambda$diffMap$0(DiffUtils.java:44)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
    at org.jfrog.common.config.diff.DiffUtils.diffMap(DiffUtils.java:44)
    at org.jfrog.common.config.diff.DiffUtils.diffCollection(DiffUtils.java:73)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.config.DiffFunctionsImpl.centralConfigDescriptorImpl(DiffFunctionsImpl.java:34)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.config.DiffFunctionsImpl.lambda$new$7(DiffFunctionsImpl.java:245)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.config.DiffFunctionsImpl.diffFor(DiffFunctionsImpl.java:16)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.findDiff(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:488)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.findDiff(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.reload(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:399)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.callReload(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:553)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.reloadConfiguration(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:537)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.saveDescriptor(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:321)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.saveAndReloadContext(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:634)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.lambda$saveAndReloadContextWithRetry$0(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:588)
    at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils.handleFunctionExecution(ExecutionUtils.java:67)
    at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils.lambda$generateExecutionRunnable$0(ExecutionUtils.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:56)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:36)
    at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils.retry(ExecutionUtils.java:48)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.saveAndReloadContextWithRetry(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:587)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.saveEditedDescriptorAndReload(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:529)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.saveEditedDescriptorAndReload(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.service.admin.reverseProxies.CreateReverseProxyService.addNewReverseProxy(CreateReverseProxyService.java:76)
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.service.admin.reverseProxies.CreateReverseProxyService.execute(CreateReverseProxyService.java:65)
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.service.ServiceExecutor.process(ServiceExecutor.java:38)
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.resource.BaseResource.runService(BaseResource.java:92)
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.resource.admin.configuration.reverseProxy.ReverseProxyResource.createReverseProxy(ReverseProxyResource.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:195)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.useAuthenticationAndContinue(AccessFilter.java:346)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:156)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-08-08 07:41:07,880 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [ERROR] (o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:111) - Last retry failed: code exception. Not trying again (Failed to reload configuration: org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.ReverseProxyDescriptor cannot be cast to org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.RepoDescriptor)
2020-08-08 07:41:07,882 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [ERROR] (o.a.r.c.e.m.GlobalExceptionMapper:48) - Could not merge and save new descriptor [org.jfrog.common.ExecutionFailed: Last retry failed: code exception. Not trying again (Failed to reload configuration: org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.ReverseProxyDescriptor cannot be cast to org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.RepoDescriptor)]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not merge and save new descriptor [org.jfrog.common.ExecutionFailed: Last retry failed: code exception. Not trying again (Failed to reload configuration: org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.ReverseProxyDescriptor cannot be cast to org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.RepoDescriptor)]
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.saveAndReloadContextWithRetry(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:600)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.saveEditedDescriptorAndReload(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:529)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.saveEditedDescriptorAndReload(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.service.admin.reverseProxies.CreateReverseProxyService.addNewReverseProxy(CreateReverseProxyService.java:76)
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.service.admin.reverseProxies.CreateReverseProxyService.execute(CreateReverseProxyService.java:65)
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.service.ServiceExecutor.process(ServiceExecutor.java:38)
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.resource.BaseResource.runService(BaseResource.java:92)
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.resource.admin.configuration.reverseProxy.ReverseProxyResource.createReverseProxy(ReverseProxyResource.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:195)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.useAuthenticationAndContinue(AccessFilter.java:346)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:156)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jfrog.common.ExecutionFailed: Last retry failed: code exception. Not trying again (Failed to reload configuration: org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.ReverseProxyDescriptor cannot be cast to org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.RepoDescriptor)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.saveAndReloadContextWithRetry(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:595)
    ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jfrog.common.ExecutionFailed: Last retry failed: code exception. Not trying again (Failed to reload configuration: org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.ReverseProxyDescriptor cannot be cast to org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.RepoDescriptor)
    at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils.handleStopError(ExecutionUtils.java:112)
    at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils.lambda$generateExecutionRunnable$0(ExecutionUtils.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:56)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:36)
    at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils.retry(ExecutionUtils.java:48)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.saveAndReloadContextWithRetry(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:587)
    ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to reload configuration: org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.ReverseProxyDescriptor cannot be cast to org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.RepoDescriptor
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.saveAndReloadContext(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:657)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.lambda$saveAndReloadContextWithRetry$0(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:588)
    at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils.handleFunctionExecution(ExecutionUtils.java:67)
    at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils.lambda$generateExecutionRunnable$0(ExecutionUtils.java:56)
    ... 91 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.ReverseProxyDescriptor cannot be cast to org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.RepoDescriptor
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.backup.BackupDescriptor.getExcludedRepositories(BackupDescriptor.java:143)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.backup.DiffFunctionsImpl.backupDescriptor(DiffFunctionsImpl.java:32)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.backup.DiffFunctionsImpl.lambda$new$2(DiffFunctionsImpl.java:42)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.backup.DiffFunctionsImpl.diffFor(DiffFunctionsImpl.java:16)
    at org.jfrog.common.config.diff.DiffUtils.diffInternalClass(DiffUtils.java:92)
    at org.jfrog.common.config.diff.DiffUtils.diffByType(DiffUtils.java:56)
    at org.jfrog.common.config.diff.DiffUtils.lambda$diffMap$0(DiffUtils.java:44)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
    at org.jfrog.common.config.diff.DiffUtils.diffMap(DiffUtils.java:44)
    at org.jfrog.common.config.diff.DiffUtils.diffCollection(DiffUtils.java:73)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.config.DiffFunctionsImpl.centralConfigDescriptorImpl(DiffFunctionsImpl.java:34)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.config.DiffFunctionsImpl.lambda$new$7(DiffFunctionsImpl.java:245)
    at org.artifactory.descriptor.config.DiffFunctionsImpl.diffFor(DiffFunctionsImpl.java:16)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.findDiff(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:488)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.findDiff(Unknown Source)
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.reload(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:399)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.callReload(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:553)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.reloadConfiguration(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:537)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.saveDescriptor(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:321)
    at org.artifactory.config.CentralConfigServiceImpl.saveAndReloadContext(CentralConfigServiceImpl.java:634)
    ... 94 common frames omitted
```

Once I encounter that error, my configuration is corrupted in the same way I described in the linked issue above. I can get back to a working state by following the same method of renaming my configuration from `latest` to `import`, but I experience the same issue anytime I make changes to the HTTP Settings.

It appears that I can change any other settings in the admin without experiencing this issue. I have not tried *every* setting, but I have tried many. It seems isolated to the Reverse Proxy settings. For now, I'm just avoiding these settings - they don't really do anything beside give you a sample VirtualHost - but I'd like to understand why this may be corrupting my configuration.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: FYI - this system is currently a clean install of v6.20.1. The backup that I restored from was running v6.11.1. So, admittedly, a slight upgrade when I did the clean install.

Comment: If you have any repositories created with the name of your reverse proxy provider (nginx, apache) try removing those repo. Could be related to https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-16463

Comment: I _swear_ I googled this and that page did not get returned. Sorry for wasting folks time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error snippet you have it looks like two modules are contradicting to each other (org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.ReverseProxyDescriptor VS org.artifactory.descriptor.repo.RepoDescriptor). Hence I believe that there seems to be a repository with name apache (or nginx) not letting another configuration to be saved to the XML (artifactory.config.latest.xml). Please try deleting the repository with that name 'apache'

Comment: Yup - that was the trick. There was a remote repository named `apache` and after deleting that I was able to save Reverse Proxy settings. That should really be escalated with JFrog because the `apache` repository is present in the default install and the conflict completely borks your system. Thanks for the help!